# Setting a Cookie on Login

Tags: php, cookies

Say my domain was www.example.com and I was setting a user's login cookie if their login credentials are correct.

How would I set the cookie? I've done the same thing with sessions and cookies on my localhost and worked perfectly fine. But when I uploaded my files on to a web server with an actual domain, it doesn't seem to work?

Cookie path: "/"

Cookie domain: ".example.com"

Thanks,

Comment: how much data are you storing in the cookie...?? is it too much?? try Setting expiration to zero and check on server..

Comment: What are the things you have tried?

Comment: PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at script:line number) in script on line  29